# Trigger that checks if the same tuple exists in two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, triggers

I wrote the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK_tuple
BEFORE INSERT ON tableB
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE IS_JOIN BOOLEAN:=FALSE

BEGIN
    SELECT tableB.column1, tableB.column2,
        CASE
         WHEN IS_JOIN:= FALSE THEN raise_application_error(-20101, 'ERROR.');
         ELSE IS_JOIN:= TRUE
        END AS CHCK_JOIN
FROM tableB 
JOIN tableA 
ON tableB.column1=tableA.column1 AND tableB.column2=tableA.column2;

END;
```

I have to check if a tuple (t1) exits in table A (with "tuple", i mean the entire row of the table with multiple columns). If exists, it has to match with t2 in table B. Before one inserts tuple t2 in table B, the trigger must activate. If t1 doesn't match with t2, the flag IS_JOIN will remain FALSE and Oracle SQL will give an error. Else, if t1 is equal to t2, IS_JOIN will be TRUE and no action will be take. I want this "check" to take place for each row that one will insert in table B. Is this the proper way to do it? If the task isn't clear, please ask for further info.

Comment: Why don't you just use a foreign key?

Comment: Instead of the trigger? Because i'm writing an example code, for a college's paper, that shows how a trigger works. Hope i've catch ur question, i'm kinda new to DB theory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_test_CHECK_tuple
BEFORE INSERT ON tableB
FOR EACH ROW
declare
  v_cnt number(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*)
    into v_cnt
    FROM tableA
    where column1=:new.column1
    and  column2=:new.column2;

  if v_cnt= 0 then
    raise_application_error(-20101, 'ERROR.');
  end if;
END;
```

`:new` means, that are the values, you want to insert. There is no other way to use that values.

btw. that is not really how a `foreign key` works, since a `foreign key` is assigned to a `primary key` or `unique key`

Comment: Can u please add a few comments about "v_cnt" ? And why are u using :
`where column1=:new.column1
    and  column2=:new.column2;`
Many thanks for ur time :)

Comment: I made an Edit, I hope it answers some questions.

Comment: Let's see if i get it : u declare a counter with "v_cnt". Then u count all the rows in tableA which have column1 and column2 equal to column1 and column2 of tableB. After that u store the number of matches in "v_cnt". Eventually, if v_cnt=0 means that no matches are found so i'll get an error. If v_cnt isn't zero it means that i've some matches. Is that right?

Comment: On a very basic level: yes.
the difference to a `foreign key` is, that since it is connected to a `unique/primary key` it can just find one match in the other table, and it doesn't really look into the other table but in the index of that table.

Comment: Perfect, that's what i was looking for. Thanks for the foreign key explanation too